# Terms used for sex and its relevance

Tags: word-request

What is the particular word for a man who is dominated by extreme sexual desire? Is this 'lusty' or " lascivious"?

Secondly, the man who controls his sexual desire, what word do we use for him? Is it 'moderate'?

Answer (score 2):

A common colloquial expression that means sexual desire or lust is

- **a high sex drive**

A very informal adjective (opinions may vary as to its vulgarity) is

- (to be) **horny**

If the OP is looking for a more formal expression, then I'd suggest

- **libido**.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libido)
>   **Libido** (/lɪˈbiːdoʊ/; colloquial: **sex drive**) is a person's overall sexual drive or desire for sexual activity.

> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/horny)
>   **horny**
>   2. *informal* Feeling or arousing sexual excitement.
>
> ‘she was making him very horny’

So a man (or woman) who has a high sex drive and constantly seeks sexual gratification can be described, colloquially, as being *[always horny](https://www.google.com/search?ei=2TJBXZPeIceBkwXzh4KIBA&q=%22always%20horny%22&oq=%22always%20horny%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...31016.34831..35642...0.0..0.76.140.2......0....1..gws-wiz.XmP53wv30hA&ved=0ahUKEwjTrqDRwd7jAhXHwKQKHfODAEEQ4dUDCAo&uact=5https://)*.

If the OP wants a *noun* for a man who has had many sexual partners, which probably stems from his high sex drive, there are several terms used in the English language, some carry more positive connotations than others.

1. **Don Juan**
   [A seducer of women; a libertine.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/don_juan)
2. **Casanova**
   [A man notorious for seducing women.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/casanova,_giovanni_jacopo)
3. **Romeo**
   [‘No Italian Romeo with an over-active libido was going to catch her’](https://www.lexico.com/en/synonym/romeo)

The following terms are usually derogatory

4. **womanizer** (*womaniser* in British English)
   [A man who engages in numerous casual sexual affairs with women.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/womanizer)
   *‘Tall, handsome, unscrupulous, with splendid curling black cavalry whiskers, Flashman is also a compulsive womaniser.’*
5. **sex addict**

Viewed by many as a debilitating illness, a person suffering from sexual addiction, is said to be *hypersexual* or informally,  a *sex addict*

> The term *sexual dependence* is also used to refer to people who report being unable to control their sexual urges, behaviors, or thoughts. Related or synonymous models of pathological sexual behavior include [*hypersexuality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersexuality) (*nymphomania* and *satyriasis* [male equivalent]), ..., *Don Juanism*...